# Making Posts on an App for both iOS and Android

Tags: android, iphone, ios

I was wondering, what is the best method for allowing consumers to post strings to your app. I would like the method used to be easily tie able into both Android and iOS so that consumers of either can view the same data. Preferably a method in which I am able to approve of the content prior to it getting on the server or whatever method would work best.

An example of what I mean is the "Funny Jokes" app that is on the Android market. They allow you to post a joke which becomes readable by everyone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, would be to have a small database online, the apps can call a script which will post the joke to a database.
Then you will have a record of all the submissions, you could use another table, which would hold all the jokes the app displays, then you can transfer as you wish.

Comment: That sounds like a really good method to go with. Would you happen to know any good resources for building a database? Thanks and I appreciate your help.

Comment: I tend to stick with MySQL and PHP, but thats mainly just because i've been taught it. If you're doing this kind of thing, its probably the best to use. There should be tutorials on setting up a database with your hosting provider, and there are plenty of tutorials for connecting PHP and MySQL around.